# What control I use to repeat List<string> in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a news model which has `Title` and `Excerpt` properties and need to display them like this image.

`ObservableCollection<NewsModel>(getNews())`

[image: demonstration of how I want to list my model]

my question is what control should I use to accomplish this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) to accomplish your task, Something like this,

```
  <ListView Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" MinWidth="80" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" MinWidth="80" />
                     </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you explain how?
I already have this:
`<ListView Name="NewsList"></<ListView>` and `NewsList.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<NewsModel>(getNews());` But I don't know what should I include between `<ListView />`

Comment: Yes it does... couldn't mark as answer within ten minutes. just marked as answer and a big Thanks to you ;)

Comment: @mhesabi: If you just need to **display** the strings and do not need to **select** them, then you can use an `ItemsControl` instead (with the same `ItemTemplate` as in Sajeetharan's answer).